# ERROR: could not open file for reading: Permission denied. SQL state: 42501

Tags: macos, postgresql, file-permissions, permission-denied, pgadmin-4

I am trying to copy an existing CSV file in a SQL table in pgAdmin4  1.5.

I am running the following query to copy the data from the CSV file:

```
COPY console_games FROM '/users/user1/Desktop/ConsoleGames.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

And I get this result:

> ```
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: could not open file "/Users/user1/Desktop/ConsoleGames.csv" for reading: Permission denied
> SQL state: 42501
> ```

I have changed the permissions of this file for all users to be read and write, but I still get the error.

Comment: 1. Try to set read permission for containing  folders 2. You did not mention if your postgres server located on the same host as the file

Comment: Thanks a lot Eugene!!!    





1. Solved my problem

Comment: I went in to every containing folder Get Info, Added posgres in the Sharings and Permissions tab and gave it Read only privilages. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem and here is how I solved

On Mac-

1. Open 'System Preferences'
2. Select 'Security and Privacy' option
3. Select 'Full Disk Access' from the list
4. Give access to PgAdmin AND postgres

Then, close and reopen your pgadmin

Comment: How to set up this in Windows 10?

Comment: This does not work for psql or DBeaverEE, unfortunately, at least not on my Mac.

Comment: I cannot find where postgreSQL is installed not matter where I searched. Obviously, it doesn't tdo the job by only giving access to pgAdmin. MacOS v.14.2 , pgAdmin 4 v.8.1

Answer (score 2):

Use PgAdmin4's bulk-load features to import the CSV. This will do a `COPY ... FROM STDIN` behind the scenes. PgAdmin4 will access the file with your user's permissions, not those of the postgres server like a direct `COPY` from file will.

Comment: Thanks a lot Craig! Adding postgres in every containing folder's Sharings and Permissions and giving it read only privileges solved the problem for me. Bulk-load features in pgAdmin seem quite useful though, can you please expand into this please?

Comment: @KostasDaglis I don't use PgAdmin, so I can't help much more there. The manual maybe? I know PgAdmin3 had import/export features, but PgAdmin4 is a rewrite - I'm not sure if it does, or where.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by creating a folder named Database in the PostgreSQL bin where I save all the data files that I want to work on. I use pgAdmin4 on both Mac and Windows. Whereas it is rather straightforward to find the bin on Windows, it is a bit tricky to find it on Mac because the Library where the bin is kept is hidden. Try to save your files on `C:\ProgramFiles\PostgreSQL\10\bin\Database` if you are using Windows and `/Library/PostgreSQL/10/bin/Database/`if you are using Mac. The Library can be found by pressing `command+shift+g` and type `~/Library` on the go to folder. Your Mac will require your password to make changes in the Library. After saving your data files here, your code on pgAdmin4 should be like this:

```
COPY console_games FROM 'C:\ProgramFiles\PostgreSQL\10\bin\Database\ConsoleGames.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

or

```
COPY console_games FROM '/Library/PostgreSQL/10/bin/Database/ConsoleGames.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: Worked great for me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac

0. Close PGAdmin
1. Open 'System Preferences'
2. Select 'Security and Privacy' option
3. Select 'Privacy'
4. Select 'Files and folders' from the list
5. Grant PgAdmin access for Documents-folder
6. Reopen PGAdmin